# Storing settings for a service application

Tags: 2010, central-administration, service-application

I created a custom service application which needs to store some settings. I've been able to create a manage.aspx management page which is usable in Central Admin. But what I don't know is where I should store the actual settings. Where do the default services store theirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtaylor/archive/2010/05/10/sharepoint-calculator-service-part-6-custom-admin-setting.aspx

Basically, a field marked by [Persisted] is enough.